# Can you explain why will be output by executing the following C code such that :'d c c d'?(pointers)

Tags: c, pointers

My output according to the following code is  `d c b a`, but it is wrong.Why?

```
char xc[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char *xp[4];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {     
    xp[i] = &xc[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {     
    *xp[i] = *xp[3-i];
}

printf("%c %c %c %c", xc[0], xc[1], xc[2], xc[3]);
```

Comment: Write out what happens at each iteration of the second loop on a piece of paper.

Comment: I dont use MS Word, it is just task from the website

Comment: Use your debugger - step through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow what you did step-by-step.

Your code is equivalent to

```
char xc[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

int i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    xc[i] = xc[3-i];
}

printf("%c %c %c %c", xc[0], xc[1], xc[2], xc[3]);
```

Then, trace is

```
i statement   xc[0] xc[1] xc[2] xc[3]
(before loop) 'a'   'b'   'c'   'd'
0 xc[0]=xc[3] 'd'   'b'   'c'   'd'
1 xc[1]=xc[2] 'd'   'c'   'c'   'd'
2 xc[2]=xc[1] 'd'   'c'   'c'   'd'
3 xc[3]=xc[0] 'd'   'c'   'c'   'd'
```

You should use a temporaly variable and be careful to swap the same pair twice to reverse the array.

```
char xc[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char *xp[4];

int i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    xp[i] = &xc[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < 3-i; i++) {
    char t = *xp[i];
    *xp[i] = *xp[3-i];
    *xp[3-i] = t;
}

printf("%c %c %c %c", xc[0], xc[1], xc[2], xc[3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Not really complex...
If you expand you second `for` it does:

```
*xp[0] = *xp[3]; // xc[0] receive 'd' value, so xc array is now {'d', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
*xp[1] = *xp[2]; // xc[1] receive 'c' value, so xc array is now {'d', 'c', 'c', 'd'}
*xp[2] = *xp[1]; // xc[2] receive 'c' value, no change
*xp[3] = *xp[0]; // xc[3] receive 'd' value, no change
```

Answer (score 0):

For `i = 0`, `xc[0]` is modified and have value `d`. For `i = 1`, `xc[1]` is modified and have value `c`. By this time `a` and `b` is no longer anywhere in your `xc` array.
Now you are using the value of `xc[0]` and `xc[1]` to modify the variables `xc[3]` and `xc[2]` respectively. The output would be

```
d c c d
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second loop, you want to use the initial values of `xp` in order to invert them, but by the time you reach the middle of the array, you have already modified the following values.

Declare a temporary variable and also change your printings in order to print `xp` instead of `xc`:

```
char xc[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
char *xp[4];
char temp;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {     
    xp[i] = &xc[i];
}

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {  
    temp = *xp[i];   
    *xp[i] = *xp[3-i];
    *xp[3-i] = temp;
}

printf(“%c %c %c %c”, xp[0], xp[1], xp[2], xp[3]);
```

Comment: This is not good because `temp` in this code doesn't store the *values* in `xc` and some values in `xc` will disappear.

Comment: The new code seems good except for duplicate `=` in `temp = = *xp[i];` and invalid character and string literals.

Comment: @MikeCAT thanks, I edited it. I had copied it from Mangomeri's initial code.

Answer (score 0):

After the first two iterations of the loop

```
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {     
    *xp[i] = *xp[3-i];
}
```

the original values of `xc[0]` and `xc[1]` were overwritten by values of 
`xc[3]` and `xc[2]` correspondingly and the array became to look like

```
char xc[4] = {'d', 'c', 'c', 'd'};
```

If you want to reverse the array then the loop can look like

```
size_t i;
size_t n = sizeof( xp ) / sizeof( *xp );

for ( i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ ) 
{
    char c = *xp[i];      
    *xp[i] = *xp[n-i-1];
    *xp[n-i-1] = c;
}
```

As result you will get that the array will look like

```
char xc[4] = {'d', 'c', 'b', 'a'};
```

That is you need to swap characters of the first half of the array with characters of the second half of the array.

Using this approach you can write a general function. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse( char s[], size_t n )
{
    size_t i;

    for ( i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }
}    

int main( void ) 
{
    char xc[] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };

    printf( "%c %c %c %c\n", xc[0], xc[1], xc[2], xc[3] );

    reverse( xc, sizeof( xc ) / sizeof( *xc ) );

    printf( "%c %c %c %c\n", xc[0], xc[1], xc[2], xc[3] );
}
```

The program output is

```
a b c d
d c b a
```